# Why doesn't Bran and company immediately leave the weirwood tree?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

**Spoilers - Don't read if you have not seen episode 5 season 6 of Game of Thrones**

So the Night's King touches Bran in his sight and the Three eyed Raven tells that he shall come to get him. Also, since the Night King touched him he can get inside the cave and all. But the Three eyed Raven starts to immediately upload everything that Bran needs to know and goes into a green sight. This seems legit.

What doesn't add up is why didnt they (Bran and the people who can walk and get out of there) leave instantly? One of the possible reason is that they need the roots of the tree to time travel? Or maybe the Three eyed raven does? But in fact Bran continues to be in the time capsule even after they leave the tree. They should have left immediately. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @BigTallJosh Let's try to be nice to the new user here. If attitudes like this become too widespread, the site won't *get* any new users who stick around.

Comment: That title wasn't really a spoiler at all. Don't worry.

Comment: I don't think that he was time travelling when he saw the NIght King.. rather it was real time

Comment: oh correct, :) but the question remains about the plot of them not leaving the cave. :(

Comment: I *think* it's because he has to make Wyllis become Hodor.  The Three Eyed Raven says something like "Listen to your friends" when the girl is yelling at Bran to wake up because they need Hodor; because otherwise Hodor isn't Hodor and the space time continuum unravels.

Comment: @pradyot considering how fast the Night King gets to the tree, I'm thinking it was Bran travelled five minutes into the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll preface this with the fact that I have not read the books, and if I am wrong on any of this feel free to correct me. Possible answers from what I gathered from the episode:

1. A very small amount of time has passed between when Bran was touched and when the walkers arrived. Hodor and Meera are seen preparing their things to leave when the walkers arrive, so they probably assumed they had more time, and wanted to get as much done at the tree as possible before leaving.
2. Bran's green sight into the past can be sustained after leaving the tree, but can only be started by touching the tree. Every sight into the past Bran has prior to episode 5 begins with him holding the tree and ends with him being taken away by the Raven, and letting go of the tree. I think due to the fact that they knew the Night King was coming, the Raven was able to help Bran sustain his sight farther than usual using his last bit of power.
3. The cave is still the safest place for them to be. Although I am not entirely sure how the mark that the Night King placed on Bran works, he may be able to find Bran anywhere. Because the cave still has resistance to the resurrected zombie type walkers it is safer than  being out in the wilderness without the protection of the cave and the Children of the Forest

Now if the mark on Bran CAN be used to find him anywhere, it seems that leaving the cave will do little to save them. Because the Night King can then simply walk out of the cave and follow Bran, killing him shortly after the final scene of episode 5. For this reason, and the fact that the Raven says, "He knows you're here," and not something like "He can track you now," my third answer is most likely (and hopefully) wrong.

Comment: FYI, the disclaimer isn't needed. The books aren't to this point yet. :)

Comment: Part 3 is wrong. The cave no longer has any protection against the undead. They just hate fire.